# How can I set up my own hotspot and a captive portal for login?

Tags: networking, wifi, captive-portal

I want to set up a hotspot from my computer which when connected by any user redirects her/him to a login page. As soon as the user is authenticated(login credentials are set up by me, of course), she/he must be redirected to a website of my choice. I am running MacOS but I have a Windows as well as a Linux environment, so OS is not a limitation.